# Chrome Extension - accessing chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow from a context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a context menu for my Chrome DevTools extension like so:

```
var CONTEXT_MENU = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title'    : 'My Context Menu',
    'contexts' : ['all'],

    'onclick' : function (info, tab) {
        alert(chrome.devtools); //[Object object]
        alert(chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow) //crashes the extension
    }
});
```

The idea here is that my extension caches some data in the inspected window (e.g. the last-clicked DOM element) and I'd like to do something with that data when the user clicks my  context menu (namely pass that data into my devtools extension pane).

Whenever I try to access the *inspectedWindow* property from inside the context menu handler, my extension crashes. Is this property protected for some reason? How else might I achieve this?

Comment: Here Here!  It makes no sense to me either.  Same problem.

Comment: Documentation says nothing about that, but it seems `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow` is just the "path" to use its methods and obtain its attributes. Being a native object does not help to guess anything else about it.

Comment: Note that the `chrome.devtools.*` APIs are only available to devtools pages. Even if the extension does not crash, you will not get anything useful out of the devtools API from the background page, unless you pass messages from/to the devtools page and the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a bug it's probably best to just file it at http://crbug.com and an engineer can address that. Thanks

Comment: I wasn't confident enough in my approach to list it as a bug, but I'll go ahead and do that. Thanks!